# Can't run batch file as Administrator on subst drive

Tags: windows, batch-file

On Windows 10. 
Steps to reproduce problem.

1) Use subst from command line to setup a drive letter. e.g.:  subst v: c:\temp

2) Create a batch file c:\temp\hello.bat:

```
echo hello 
pause
```

3) in windows explorer, go to v: drive. 
Try to run hello.bat by right clicking, and selecting Run As Administrator. 
The expected Windows security question "Do you want to allow this app to make changes to your device?" comes up. When you answer Yes, nothing seems to happen. 
I know I can go to c:\temp in Windows Explorer, and this will work, but it's not ideal.

I gather it is something to do with Run As Administrator context not being able to see the subst drive? 
Are there any workarounds, to be able to get this to work? So that batch files can be run in Windows Explorer on the subst drive as Administrator.

EDIT: 
A workaround of sorts: 
In Windows Explorer, go to c: drive. Then c:\temp. Create a shortcut to hello.bat. Also tick the Run as Administrator option.

In Windows Explorer, go back to v: drive. Double click the shortcut to run hello.bat as administrator. This seems to work.

Mods: feel free to move this question to Superuser, if it turns out there is nothing you can do in the batch file itself to make this work.

Comment: Try running cmd.exe as administrator and look to see if the v: drive still exists.  If it doesn't, rerun subst in the administrator context.

Comment: yeah, v: drive doesn't exist. The subst is setup in another batch file, which runs in the context of the current user.

Comment: A virtual drive as created by using drive substitution command `subst` or network drive mapping command `net use` exists only in context of the user account used to create the virtual drive. So `subst` must be executed by the account which wants to use that drive substitution.

Comment: @mofi, for `net use` the mapped drive is setup by the multiple provider router (MPR), which has a policy to reflect the mapping to the linked token's logon session if the user has a UAC split token. To enable this policy, set "EnableLinkedConnections" to a DWORD value of 1 in the registry key "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System", and restart the system. subst.exe, OTOH, just calls `DefineDosDeviceW`, which is implemented by the desktop session server (csrss.exe) only for the requesting user's logon session, not a linked logon session.